# how to call an alert box in code behind on button click in?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a button , When Clicks on it , I have to generate an alert box with "Ok" "Cancel" button. I have done like this, script on .aspx is,

```
 <script>

   function getConfirmationValue2() 
   {var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value2";
        if (confirm("Save??")) {
            confirm_value.value = "OK";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "CANCEL";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
   } </script>

      <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_submit"   runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/BtnSubmit.png" CausesValidation="true"    
                    onclick="btn_submit_click"/>
```

on button click,

```
  protected void btn_submit_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
                       if(TextBox1.Text="start")
                        {
                        btn_submit.OnClientClick = @"return getConfirmationValue2();";
                        string confirmValue122 = Request.Form["confirm_value2"];

                        if (confirmValue122 == "OK")
                        {
                            //updating the datas
                          }

                       }}}
```

It generates the alert box only when clicks two times on button. What will be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind it in markup of button like `OnClientClick = "return getConfirmationValue2();"`

Markup of button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_submit"   
    runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/BtnSubmit.png" 
    CausesValidation="true"  
    OnClientClick = "return getConfirmationValue2();" <== Added code here   
    onclick="btn_submit_click"/>
```

**It generates the alert box only when clicks two times on button. What will be the problem?**

`OnClientClick` is binded when you click for first time, thus you are not getting alert box for first click.

If You want to `register` it in CodeBehind, I would suggest you to use [`Control.Init`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init.aspx) event or `Page_Load` event

Comment: I know OnClientClick = "return getConfirmationValue2();" this will work. But we have to put it in code behind. Is there any another way?

Comment: @ARATHY, If You want to register it in CodeBehind, I would suggest you to use `Control.Init` event or `Page_Load` event

Comment: but how is it done? I have to check a condition, and only after need to generate alert box. not at the instant button click